# jsonlint is not defined - codemirror

Tags: javascript, angularjs, codemirror, ui-codemirror

I have ui-codemirror implemented in angular application. After turning on lint I have an error in console:

```
ReferenceError: jsonlint is not defined
at https://localhost:9000/bower_components/codemirror/addon/lint/json-lint.js:20:3
```

lint.js:20:3 :

```
  jsonlint.parseError = function(str, hash) {
```

These are my options for editor

```
     $scope.cmOption = {
        value: "/*WRITE YOUR INSTRUCTION HERE*/",
        lineWrapping : true,
        lineNumbers: true,
        textWrapping: true,
        indentWithTabs: true,
        readOnly: false,
        theme: 'neat',
        mode: "application/json",
        matchBrackets: true,
        autoCloseBrackets: true,
        gutters: ["CodeMirror-lint-markers"],
        lint: true
    };
```

And here lint.js included (at the very bottom of my index, after all other codemirror scripts)

```
<script src="bower_components/codemirror/addon/lint/lint.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/codemirror/addon/lint/javascript-lint.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/codemirror/addon/lint/json-lint.js"></script>
```

Comment: What does line #20 of `bower_components/codemirror/addon/lint/json-lint.js` do?

Comment: @AlexMcMillan  jsonlint.parseError = function(str, hash) {

Comment: That was intended to help you begin debugging ;)  Go find out why `jsonlint` doesn't exist.  I assume it is `import`ed or `require`d at the top of `json-lint.js`, but perhaps it is expected to be global.

Comment: @AlexMcMillan I found the culprit. I am blind..really: "// Depends on jsonlint.js from https://github.com/zaach/jsonlint" 
haha :)